# Wildfly error start up. Possible reasons?

Tags: jboss, wildfly

Bellow is the output of server.log

```
2023-04-06 10:20:23,720 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "air-diffusion.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./air-diffusion" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./air-diffusion: Failed to start service
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'captchaGeneratorServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.octo.captcha.service.image.ImageCaptchaService com.softavac.captcha.server.service.CaptchaGeneratorServiceImpl.imageCaptchaService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'imageCaptchaService' defined in class path resource [com/softavac/config/root/CaptchaConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.octo.captcha.service.multitype.GenericManageableCaptchaService com.softavac.config.root.CaptchaConfig.imageCaptchaService()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'captchaImageEngine' defined in class path resource [com/softavac/config/root/CaptchaConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.octo.captcha.engine.GenericCaptchaEngine com.softavac.config.root.CaptchaConfig.captchaImageEngine()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'captchaFactory' defined in class path resource [com/softavac/config/root/CaptchaConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.octo.captcha.image.ImageCaptchaFactory com.softavac.config.root.CaptchaConfig.captchaFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/image/codec/jpeg/ImageFormatException
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'captchaGeneratorServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.octo.captcha.service.image.ImageCaptchaService com.softavac.captcha.server.service.CaptchaGeneratorServiceImpl.imageCaptchaService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'imageCaptchaService' defined in class path resource [com/softavac/config/root/CaptchaConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.octo.captcha.service.multitype.GenericManageableCaptchaService com.softavac.config.root.CaptchaConfig.imageCaptchaService()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'captchaImageEngine' defined in class path resource [com/softavac/config/root/CaptchaConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.octo.captcha.engine.GenericCaptchaEngine com.softavac.config.root.CaptchaConfig.captchaImageEngine()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'captchaFactory' defined in class path resource [com/softavac/config/root/CaptchaConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.octo.captcha.image.ImageCaptchaFactory com.softavac.config.root.CaptchaConfig.captchaFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/image/codec/jpeg/ImageFormatException
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.octo.captcha.service.image.ImageCaptchaService com.softavac.captcha.server.service.CaptchaGeneratorServiceImpl.imageCaptchaService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'imageCaptchaService' defined in class path resource [com/softavac/config/root/CaptchaConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.octo.captcha.service.multitype.GenericManageableCaptchaService com.softavac.config.root.CaptchaConfig.imageCaptchaService()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'captchaImageEngine' defined in class path resource [com/softavac/config/root/CaptchaConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.octo.captcha.engine.GenericCaptchaEngine com.softavac.config.root.CaptchaConfig.captchaImageEngine()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'captchaFactory' defined in class path resource [com/softavac/config/root/CaptchaConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.octo.captcha.image.ImageCaptchaFactory com.softavac.config.root.CaptchaConfig.captchaFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/image/codec/jpeg/ImageFormatException
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'imageCaptchaService' defined in class path resource [com/softavac/config/root/CaptchaConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.octo.captcha.service.multitype.GenericManageableCaptchaService com.softavac.config.root.CaptchaConfig.imageCaptchaService()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'captchaImageEngine' defined in class path resource [com/softavac/config/root/CaptchaConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.octo.captcha.engine.GenericCaptchaEngine com.softavac.config.root.CaptchaConfig.captchaImageEngine()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'captchaFactory' defined in class path resource [com/softavac/config/root/CaptchaConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.octo.captcha.image.ImageCaptchaFactory com.softavac.config.root.CaptchaConfig.captchaFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/image/codec/jpeg/ImageFormatException
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.octo.captcha.service.multitype.GenericManageableCaptchaService com.softavac.config.root.CaptchaConfig.imageCaptchaService()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'captchaImageEngine' defined in class path resource [com/softavac/config/root/CaptchaConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.octo.captcha.engine.GenericCaptchaEngine com.softavac.config.root.CaptchaConfig.captchaImageEngine()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'captchaFactory' defined in class path resource [com/softavac/config/root/CaptchaConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.octo.captcha.image.ImageCaptchaFactory com.softavac.config.root.CaptchaConfig.captchaFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/image/codec/jpeg/ImageFormatException
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'captchaImageEngine' defined in class path resource [com/softavac/config/root/CaptchaConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.octo.captcha.engine.GenericCaptchaEngine com.softavac.config.root.CaptchaConfig.captchaImageEngine()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'captchaFactory' defined in class path resource [com/softavac/config/root/CaptchaConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.octo.captcha.image.ImageCaptchaFactory com.softavac.config.root.CaptchaConfig.captchaFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/image/codec/jpeg/ImageFormatException
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.octo.captcha.engine.GenericCaptchaEngine com.softavac.config.root.CaptchaConfig.captchaImageEngine()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'captchaFactory' defined in class path resource [com/softavac/config/root/CaptchaConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.octo.captcha.image.ImageCaptchaFactory com.softavac.config.root.CaptchaConfig.captchaFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/image/codec/jpeg/ImageFormatException
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'captchaFactory' defined in class path resource [com/softavac/config/root/CaptchaConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.octo.captcha.image.ImageCaptchaFactory com.softavac.config.root.CaptchaConfig.captchaFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/image/codec/jpeg/ImageFormatException
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.octo.captcha.image.ImageCaptchaFactory com.softavac.config.root.CaptchaConfig.captchaFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/image/codec/jpeg/ImageFormatException
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/image/codec/jpeg/ImageFormatException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.ImageFormatException from [Module \"deployment.air-diffusion.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
```

2023-04-06 10:20:24,102 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "air-diffusion.war" (runtime-name : "air-diffusion.war")
2023-04-06 10:20:24,113 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./air-diffusion: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./air-diffusion: Failed to start service

2023-04-06 10:20:24,193 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://xxx.xxx.xxx.109:9990/management
2023-04-06 10:20:24,195 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://xxx.xxx.xxx.109:9990
2023-04-06 10:20:24,203 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek" started (with errors) in 71225ms - Started 356 of 414 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 92 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
2023-04-06 10:20:24,486 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'air-diffusion.war#AirDiffusionPU'
2023-04-06 10:20:24,539 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'air-diffusion.war#AirDiffusionPU'
2023-04-06 10:20:25,158 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment air-diffusion.war (runtime-name: air-diffusion.war) in 731ms
2023-04-06 10:20:25,476 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "air-diffusion.war" (runtime-name: "air-diffusion.war")
2023-04-06 10:20:25,485 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.ArgumentTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindErrorsTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EscapeBodyTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EvalTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.HtmlEscapeTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.NestedPathTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.ParamTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.ThemeTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.TransformTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.UrlTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ButtonTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.CheckboxTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.CheckboxesTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ErrorsTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.HiddenInputTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionsTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.PasswordInputTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.RadioButtonTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.RadioButtonsTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.TextareaTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.persistenceunit."air-diffusion.war#AirDiffusionPU" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./air-diffusion (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."air-diffusion.war".deploymentCompleteService]
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./air-diffusion

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/image/codec/jpeg/ImageFormatException is your issue. Those classes were removed in Java9, could this be your issue ?

Comment: No. The app was working fine till the server upgraded from centOs to Almalinux.
A problem with mysql connector also cocur, but after updating the connector, worked.

Comment: Did the Java version change?  An upgrade could have easily upgraded to a newer version.  What was the Java version previously and what is the Java version now?

Comment: Same.
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_362"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_362-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.362-b09, mixed mode)

javac -version
javac 1.7.0_75